# how to display mysql data to coloumns into rows

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

My sql query shows result in the format below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsrBQ.png' />

But how to display in this way ;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtXB3.png' />

Comment: I am using laravel 5.4 and creating a query using foreach loop and using it DB::raw() select When I check the query using toSql() it shows the perfect query I wanted and giving perfect query result but on using get() the loop query get overwritten

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your query and use GROUP BY clause.
That should solve your problem

Comment: A comment would have worked perfectly as you have enough reputation to post comments and also this doesn't provide any answer to OPs question

Comment: I am using laravel 5.4 and creating a query using foreach and using it DB::raw() select

When I check the query run by usinh toSql() it showthe perfect query I wanted and giving perfect query result but on using get() the loop query get overwritten